# How can I use SUM() to sum my result array?

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

My current method to add the rows together is like so:

```
$totalxp = $row['Attackxp'] + $row['Defencexp'] + $row['Strengthxp'] + $row['Hitpointsxp'] + $row['Rangedxp'] + $row['Prayerxp'] + $row['Magicxp'] + $row['Cookingxp'] + $row['Woodcuttingxp'] + $row['Fletchingxp'] + $row['Fishingxp'] + $row['Firemakingxp'] + $row['Craftingxp'] + $row['Smithingxp'] + $row['Miningxp'] + $row['Herblorexp'] + $row['Agilityxp'] + $row['Thievingxp'] + $row['Slayerxp'] + $row['Farmingxp'] + $row['Runecraftxp'] + $row['Constructionxp'];
```

But then I saw SUM() and I tried this:

```
SELECT SUM(xp) FROM skills WHERE playerName='Undercover'
```

It works but I needed all the values of xp, so I tried adding `%xp` but it wont work.

How could I use the Sum() function to add all the rows up instead of straining PHP?

Comment: Can we see your table structure?

Comment: Are the values all in the same row in different columns, or in multiple rows in the same column? SUM is meant for aggregates over multiple rows in the same column/expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate functions (IE: SUM, MIN, MAX, COUNT, etc) don't work across columns--they work on the values for the specific column, based on the grouping (`GROUP BY`) and filteration (`JOIN` and/or `WHERE` clause).

To add up values across columns, you need to add them like you would for normal mathematical equations:

```
SELECT Attackxp + Defencexp + Strengthxp + Hitpointsxp + Rangedxp + Prayerxp + Magicxp + Cookingxp+ Woodcuttingxp + Fletchingxp + Fishingxp + Firemakingxp + Craftingxp + Smithingxp + Miningxp + Herblorexp + Agilityxp + Thievingxp + Slayerxp + Farmingxp + Runecraftxp + Constructionxp AS total_xp
  FROM skills 
 WHERE playerName = 'Undercover'
```

If you have more than one record associated to a playername, *then* you can use an aggregate function:

```
SELECT SUM(Attackxp + Defencexp + Strengthxp + Hitpointsxp + Rangedxp + Prayerxp + Magicxp + Cookingxp+ Woodcuttingxp + Fletchingxp + Fishingxp + Firemakingxp + Craftingxp + Smithingxp + Miningxp + Herblorexp + Agilityxp + Thievingxp + Slayerxp + Farmingxp + Runecraftxp + Constructionxp) AS total_xp
  FROM skills 
 WHERE playerName = 'Undercover'
```

Comment: +1 Your reputation rounds off to 56k now. **-Sudden flash of nostalgia-**

Comment: I don't catch that "don't work across columns", and that statement that they works for specific column, based on the grouping is not totally right.

Comment: @Vash: I'm not clear on what you don't understand.  With the exception of COUNT accepting *, I can't think of any aggregates that accept more than one column as a parameter.

Comment: @OMG Now I understand what You had in mind, that functions does not allow to use more then one parameter.

Comment: @Vash: Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

That depend of the table data if each player is one entity (row) then is enaught to add columns:

```
SELECT Attackxp  + Defencexp + Strengthxp + Hitpointsxp +Rangedxp + Prayerxp + Magicxp + Cookingxp + Woodcuttingxp + Fletchingxp + Fishingxp + Firemakingxp + Craftingxp + Smithingxp + Miningxp + Herblorexp + Agilityxp + Thievingxp + Slayerxp + Farmingxp + Runecraftxp + Constructionxp 
As totalSkills FROM skills WHERE playerName = 'Undercover'
```

But is there more rows per player then You will need to sum also the rows

```
SELECT SUM(Attackxp  + Defencexp + Strengthxp + Hitpointsxp +Rangedxp + Prayerxp + Magicxp + Cookingxp + Woodcuttingxp + Fletchingxp + Fishingxp + Firemakingxp + Craftingxp + Smithingxp + Miningxp + Herblorexp + Agilityxp + Thievingxp + Slayerxp + Farmingxp + Runecraftxp + Constructionxp) 
As totalSkills FROM skills WHERE playerName = 'Undercover'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(`Attackxp`) + SUM(`Defencexp`) + ... AS `total_sum`
  FROM skills
 WHERE playerName='Undercover'
```